# Not adding correctly

Tags: floating-point

Quick question. I know PHP does type conversion on the fly - if they make sense, string to integers etc. Yet on these values pulled from the database, they add up incorrectly. I know there's a mix of datatypes there but i thought it'd resolve that and add them. The total in the final output of the page, I apply the number_format function to which i require it to 2 places.

Any help greatly appreciated, as usual.

```
 ["haulage_cost"]=>
  string(29) 35.00"
  ["freight"]=>
  float(15.432098765432)
  ["BAF"]=>
  int(0)
  ["THC"]=>
  float(15)
  ["docs"]=>
  string(5) "25.00"
  ["customs"]=>
  string(5) "35.00"
  ["security"]=>
  string(4) "6.50"
  ["COO"]=>
  string(5) "50.00"
  ["HAZ"]=>
  int(0)
  ["AMS"]=>
  int(0)
  ["DTHC"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total"]=>
  float(146.93209876543)
}
```

Comment: What result did you expect, and what datatype did you think it would be represented in?

Comment: It's ok, I've sorted things with a preg_match() - to get the foat, well string. string(29) 35.00" was the concern. I just wanted that price, so it could be added finally and summarised with the rest of the costs. I couldn't work out why it was such a long and empty string and when i looked at the script, my colleague wrote, I saw nothing immediately wrong or that would cause a string to be returned of such a length. Thanks.